# Is it possible to use more css properties for JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx

Can I specify more css properties for the JavaFX elements? I already noticed there are some limitations https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introlimitations but is this list all of the properties I can set?

For example I can't change the background color for the Node, besides using .setFill?

Comment: Of course you can change the background color with `-fx-background-color`. It is on the link you posted! Unless you modify the javafx CSS engine, I don't think you can create other properties

Comment: What kind of `Node`? Different node have different sets of properties. You can set the background color of a `Region` (or subclass) with `-fx-background-color`, and you can set the fill of a `Shape` (or subclass) with `-fx-fill`. The properties for each `Node` type are documented in the documentation you linked. It is possible (though very complex) to define your own node subclass and support custom CSS properties. Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @James_D I was trying to set the background color for an object that extends the Circle class. What I did after creation of it is object.setStyle("-fx-background-color: ##96ceb4"); but it did not work.

Comment: Read the docs. Circles don't have a `-fx-background-color` property. You need `object.setStyle("-fx-fill: #96ceb4;");`. Since circle is a subclass of [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape) it has a `-fx-fill` property.

Answer (score 0):

As Kwoinkwoin posted you could change the backround using the predefined -fx css classes. 
If you need more css customization rules you can take a look at Pseudo classes which Hendrik Ebbers wrote a great article [javafx and pseudo classes](http://www.guigarage.com/2016/02/javafx-and-css-pseudo-classes/)